# Discord.py Giveaway Winner Mention Not Working

Tags: discord, discord.py

I am using cogs (I'm new to cogs) to create a giveaway system. Of course, the giveaway system needs the bot to create a reaction to the post and then it can determine the winner based on those who clicked the reaction. Once the giveaway ends, I receive an error.

This is the code I was using:

```
@commands.command()
    @commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
    async def giveaway(self, ctx: commands.Context):
        await ctx.send("Let's start with this giveaway! Answer these questions within 15 seconds!")

        questions = ["Which channel should it be hosted in?", 
                    "What should be the duration of the giveaway? (s|m|h|d)",
                    "What is the prize of the giveaway?"]
        answers = []
        def check(m):
            return m.author == ctx.author and m.channel == ctx.channel 
        for i in questions:
            await ctx.send(i)
            try:
                msg = await self.bot.wait_for('message', timeout=15.0, check=check)
            except asyncio.TimeoutError:
                await ctx.send('You didn\'t answer in time, please be quicker next time!')
                return
            else:
                answers.append(msg.content)
        try:
            c_id = int(answers[0][2:-1])
        except:
            await ctx.send(f"You didn't mention a channel properly. Do it like this {ctx.channel.mention} next time.")
            return
        channel = self.bot.get_channel(c_id)
        time = convert(answers[1])
        if time == -1:
            await ctx.send(f"You didn't answer the time with a proper unit. Use (s|m|h|d) next time!")
            return
        elif time == -2:
            await ctx.send(f"The time must be an integer. Please enter an integer next time")
            return            
        prize = answers[2]
        await ctx.send(f"The Giveaway will be in {channel.mention} and will last {answers[1]}!")
        embed = discord.Embed(title = "Giveaway!", description = f"{prize}", color = ctx.author.color)
        embed.add_field(name = "Hosted by:", value = ctx.author.mention)
        embed.set_footer(text = f"Ends {answers[1]} from now!")
        my_msg = await channel.send(embed = embed)
        await my_msg.add_reaction("")
        await asyncio.sleep(time)
        new_msg = await channel.fetch_message(my_msg.id)
        users = await new_msg.reactions[0].users().flatten()
        users.pop(users.index(self.bot.user))

        winner = random.choice(users)

        await channel.send(f"Congratulations! {winner.mention} won {prize}!")

def convert(time):
        pos = ["s","m","h","d"]

        time_dict = {"s" : 1, "m" : 60, "h" : 3600 , "d" : 3600*24}

        unit = time[-1]

        if unit not in pos:
            return -1
        try:
            val = int(time[:-1])
        except:
            return -2


        return val * time_dict[unit]
```

And this is the error I am getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Human\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 229, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\Users\Human\Documents\TestBot\cogs\giveaways.py", line 78, in giveaway
    users = await new_msg.reactions[0].users().flatten()
AttributeError: 'async_generator' object has no attribute 'flatten'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Human\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 1349, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\Human\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 1023, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)  # type: ignore
  File "C:\Users\Human\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 238, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'async_generator' object has no attribute 'flatten'
```

Frankly I have no idea what is going on. It's supposed to mention the user who wins the giveaway. Hopefully someone can figure out why on earth I am getting an error. Thanks.

Comment: The error send straight forward enough... `users = await new_msg.reactions[0].users().flatten()
AttributeError: 'async_generator' object has no attribute 'flatten'`

Comment: Still no idea what a solution would be...

Comment: @WizardWarrior The example can easily be found in the [docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=reaction%20users#discord.Reaction.users), you should try it sometimes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are likely using Discord.py 2.0+ which works differently in some ways to older versions. The docs have examples of exactly what changes you need to make to migrate - https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/migrating.html#moving-away-from-custom-asynciterator

Particularly, the `AsyncIterator`s were changed so, as it says in the docs, there is no more `flatten()` attribute.

```
# before
users = await reaction.users().flatten()

# after
users = [user async for user in reaction.users()]
```

In your case, you have this old code:

```
users = await new_msg.reactions[0].users().flatten()
```

Following the above example, it would be changed to:

```
users = [user async for user in new_msg.reactions[0].users()]
```